# How to grep a specific path from output of unzip -l

Tags: regex, bash, grep, unzip

I need to extract the path to the Info.plist file right after the .app folder.

```
$ unzip -l test.ipa | grep Info.plist
258  05-25-2018 11:52   Payload/test.app/CDVLaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist
2197  05-25-2018 11:52   Payload/test.app/Info.plist
```

The problem is that the .app folder is named different in every .ipa file. I can't grep for `Payload/test.app/Info.plist`. I've tried:

```
$ unzip -l test.ipa | grep Payload/*.app/Info.plist
$ unzip -l test.ipa | grep "Payload/..app/Info.plist"
```

which yields nothing.

How would the correct grep argument look like? Also how would I only extract the path(`Payload/test.app/Info.plist`) instead of the whole row (`2197  05-25-2018 11:52   Payload/test.app/Info.plist`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unzip -l test.ipa | grep -o 'Payload/.*\.app/Info\.plist'
```

The regex you need is `Payload/.*\.app/Info\.plist`. Notice the escaped dots - they have to be matched literally.

`.*` will be interpreted by shell unless you enclose the grep parameter into quotes (double quotes would also be fine in your case since no variable expansion collision may happen in this particular expression).

Finally, `-o` switch tells grep output only the match.

Answer (score 1):

In a pattern `.` means any character and `*` means 0 or more times the preceeded character.

Your command should be:

```
unzip -l test.ipa | grep -o 'Payload/.*\.app/Info\.plist'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you aren't certain about whether all paths begin with `Payload`, try

`unzip -l test.ipa | grep -P '(?<=\s)\S*Info.plist'`

which matches all non whitespace characters before `Info.plist`.